# Lorentz Transformation at t=0

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

Suppose I have two reference frames $S$ and $S'$, where $S'$ is moving with velocity $v$ with respect to $S$.

The Lorentz transformation equation for time in reference frame $S$ is given by:
$$t'=\gamma\left(t-x\frac{v}{c^2}\right)$$
where $\gamma$ is the [Lorentz factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor).

Now for an event happening at $t=0$ and at some position $x$ in $S$ frame, then $t'<0$ for $S'$ frame. But if $x=0$ then $t'=0$.

How should I interpret this result?

Answer (score 2):

The interpretation is that two events being simultaneous as measured in frame $S$ doesn't imply that the events are simultaneous in frame $S'$.  Which events count as being "simultaneous" depends on the frame of reference.  This is known as the [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity).

Added clarification due to comment:

The coinciding of the origins is an event, call it event $A$.  The coordinates of $A$ as measured in $S$ are $t_A=0$, $x_A=0$, and the coordinates of $A$ as measured in $S'$ are $t'_A=0$, $x'_A=0$.

You're also considering another event, call it $B$, whose coordinates as measured in $S$ are $t_B=0$, $x_B=x$.  As measured in $S'$, the $t'$ coordinate of $B$ is $t'_{B}=-\gamma x v/c^2$.

$t'_B$ being negative (if $x>0$) means that according to $S'$, event $B$ occurs before event $A$.  However, if $x=0$, then $B$ is the same event as $A$, so $t'_B=0$ and $x'_B=0$.

There is no physical discontinuity between the situations where $x=0$ and $x>0$, i.e., between the situations where $t'_B=0$ and $t'_B<0$.  It's just that the further away event $B$ is from event $A$ spatially, the bigger the difference will be between $t'_B$ and $t_B$.